# TestMethod defined in Abstract class not in Test Explorer

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm rewriting a solution that has a bunch of unit tests, many of which do the exact same thing on different entities.

I'm trying to refactor the tests to define default implementation, but I'm running into issues.

I'm not seeing the tests declared TestMethod in the BaseTestClass in the Test Explorer.
Am I missing something?
Ideally I'd see a complete set of methods from the base and the concrete class for every concrete implementation.

Here's what I have:

```
public Interface SomeTestInterface
{
  ... signatures of methods with are required...
  public void TestConnection();

}

[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseTestClass : SomeTestInterface
{
  .. a mix of default implementation and abstract methods

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestConnection() {
  AssertIsTrue(operator.TestConnection());

  }

  [TestMethod]
  public abstract void TestQuery();

}

[TestClass]
public class ConcreteClassA : BaseTestClass
{
  ... overriding of abstract methods


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The unit tests will not run unless they are explicitly declared with the TestMethod attribute. If you want to avoid having to add the attribute to every implementation of TestQuery could do something like this:

```
public interface SomeTestInterface
{
    void TestConnection();
}

[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseTestClass : SomeTestInterface
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestConnection()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestQueryBase()
    {
        TestQuery();
    }

    public abstract void TestQuery();
}

[TestClass]
public class ConcreteClassA : BaseTestClass
{
    public override void TestQuery()
    {

    }
}
```